# How to Change my TabbarGroup Color Change?

Tags: iphone, titanium

I want to make a tabbar application. In this application I Want to change my Tabbar Background Color Change. How I Can perform This? (Titanium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been asked and answered.

[Custom Tabgroup Appcelerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729140/custom-tabgroup-appcelerator)

https://gist.github.com/853935

Comment: But, one Problem in this. When I navigate one to another window and i want to hide tabbar then this view is show. how i solve this problem (Hide and Show with Tabbar). any solution than suggest me. Thanks

Comment: Looks at the source. It's just a view that gets added to the tab group. Hide it like you'd hide any other view (tabGroup.overrideTabs).